# How to convert svg data to image/image base64 using java script

Tags: javascript, extjs, svg, internet-explorer-9, extjs4.1

I have done application using Extjs 4.1 provided option to user to print screens. In all browser working fine without ant issues. But in IE9 except graph(Svg) everything is printing. **Can any one tell me how to print graphs in IE9. or how to convert svg data to image base64 ?** Great appreciated. Thank you

**Code is here**

```
var metricsNumberId = document.getElementById('metricsNumberId');
newWin= window.open();
newWin.document.write('<img src="'+metricsNumberId.innerHTML+'" width="400" height="400""/>');// This one way i have tried is not worked
newWin.document.write('+metricsNumberId.innerHTML+');// This another way i have tried is not worked
newWin.document.close();
newWin.focus();
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
newWin='';
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using RaphaelJS and loading in the SVG using https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import or https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic. After that you can export it  using http://www.phpepe.com/2012/07/export-raphael-graphic-to-image.html Take a look at that. In my situation I needed to present the user with a visual representation and buttons to edit/move the image around.